# Reusable XAML control in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have written a nice `Grid` with some other controls like: `Entry` and `Image` and now I would like to reuse it the simplest way.

This is my control for `Email` property:

```
<Grid
                Style="{StaticResource gridEntryStyle}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="7" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <controls:ExtendedEntry
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Text="{Binding UserEmail, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Placeholder="{i18n:Translate UserEmailPlaceholder}"
                    Style="{StaticResource entryStyle}">

                    <controls:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior 
                            EventName="Focused" 
                            Command="{Binding ControlFocusCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="UserEmail"/>
                        <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior 
                            EventName="Unfocused" 
                            Command="{Binding ControlUnfocusedCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="UserEmail"/>
                    </controls:ExtendedEntry.Behaviors>

                </controls:ExtendedEntry>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Source="clear.png"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsEntryFocused}"
                    Style="{StaticResource imageClearStyle}">

                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="UserEmail"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                </Image>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Source="lineWhite.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource imageLineStyle}"/>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Source="linePure.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource imageLineStyle}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsError}"/>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Source="lineGradient.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource imageLineStyle}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsEntryFocused}"/>

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"
                    Style="{StaticResource labelErrorStyle}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsError}"/>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Source="error.png"
                    Style="{StaticResource imageErrorStyle}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsError}"/>

            </Grid>
```

I would like to reuse it for example as follows:

```
<usercontrols:EntryControl 
                MainText="{Binding UserEmail}"
                MainTextPlaceholder="{i18n:Translate UserEmailPlaceholder}" />
```

For now even this simple example is not working and I have no idea how to define `Command` in this control. For now I have:

```
public partial class EntryControl : ContentView
{
    public EntryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "MainText",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(string),
            defaultValue: string.Empty,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string MainText
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(MainTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(MainTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MainTextPlaceholderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "MainTextPlaceholder", 
            returnType: typeof(string), 
            declaringType: typeof(string), 
            defaultValue: string.Empty, 
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string MainTextPlaceholder
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(MainTextPlaceholderProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(MainTextPlaceholderProperty, value);}
    }
}
```

Is this the right way? or is this even possible in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Please be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: First thing, I have noticed, that `declaringType` should be type of control declaring `BindableProperty`.

Comment: Not working means that when I type: <usercontrols:EntryControl 
     MainText="{Binding UserEmail}"
     MainTextPlaceholder="{i18n:Translate UserEmailPlaceholder}" /> values MainText and MainTextPlaceholder are not binded to theirs values.

Answer (score 4):

XAML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="ApplicationName.Controls.EntryControl"
      Style="{StaticResource gridEntryStyle}">
    </Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
namespace ApplicationName.Controls
{
    public partial class EntryControl : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(Command),
            returnType: typeof(ICommand),
            declaringType: typeof(EntryControl),
            defaultValue: null,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public string Command
        {
            get { return (string)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public EntryControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ApplicationName.Controls;assembly=ApplicationName"

<controls:EntryLabel/>
```

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Here is a [sample](https://github.com/gromadskyi/HoldingViewSample/blob/master/HoldingViewSample/HoldingViewSample/MainPage.xaml), but control w/o xaml.

Comment: Another implementation using DataBinding https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73350/help-with-reusable-xaml-user-control-icommand-and-viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

Your issue with BindingContext

In short, you have to write down the bindings inside your control like this {Binding UserEmail, Mode=TwoWay, **Source={x:Reference myControlTHIS}}**, where 'myControlTHIS' is x:Name="TheCategoryHeader".

---

More info:

BindingContext is everything when it comes to getting things to bind and work right in an MVVM app – WPF or Xamarin. Controls inherit context from the parent control unless a different context is explicitly assigned. That’s what we need to do here. We need to tell each UI element (label, entry, button, etc.) to explicitly look at this control for its context in order to find those BindingProperties we just made. This is one of the rare occasions when we actually give a XAML element a name: When it is going to be referenced by another XAML element within the XAML itself. To the ContentView, add a tag naming the control ‘this’. That’s right. We’re going to keep to the Microsoft naming and have this item refer to itself as 'myControlTHIS'. It makes all of us comfortable and the code and markup easy to read and follow.

We can now use 'myControlTHIS' as a reference source telling the rest of our XAML where to look for properties to bind to.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't find this anywhere else. In this case the binding context inside the control is different from outside the control